# Letting users update their own posts with CanCan and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am using **Devise and CanCan** to manage users and user-rights.
What I want is: Ordinary users shall be able to **update their own Posts**.
The most important Model is called Activity.

In the ability-model I have for ordinary members:

```
elsif user.role? :Member
   can :read, :all
   can :create, :all
   can :manage, Activity, :user_id=>user.id
```

(Thanks to Yuriy Goldshtrakh for the syntax of the third line)

In the index-view of the Activities, I have:

```
<% if can? :update, activity  %>
<br />
<%= link_to 'Update', edit_activity_path(activity) %>
<% end %>

<% if can? :delete, activity  %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', activity, :confirm => 'Really?', :method => :delete %>

<% end %>
```

This works: It only shows the **update and the delete-link**, if the Activity was created by the current member.

However, if the member updates the activity, the changes are not saved and the member is not sent back to the activity - as he/she should be after a successful update.

Here is the update-action in the Activities-controller:

```
  # PUT /activities/1.xml
```

def update

```
authorize! :update, @activity

@activity = Activity.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @activity.update_attributes(params[:activity])
    format.html { redirect_to(@activity, :notice => 'Activity was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @activity.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

The question is: Why ist the activity not updated correctly?
I am grateful for all ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap line 1 and 3 of the `ActivitiesController#update`

```
def update
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])

  authorize! :update, @activity
  ...
end
```

You could also use [the preferred way with Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions): `load_and_authorize_resource`

Comment: You are right! That was the reason why it did not work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

if your post and comments belong to the user you can do this

```
can :manage, [Post,Comment], :user_id=>user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

For example ability:

```
if user.role?(:author)
        can :create, Article
        can :update, Article do |article|
          article.try(:user) == user
        end
      end
```

Try do with this tutorial: [Railscasts CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)
Maybe help